# How do I set a radio button value based on a condition of several other radio button selections?

Tags: groovy, jira

Just need a little direction in finishing my script, I need to gather the values of several radio button fields and perform an if/then condition to determine the default radio button value of one other. This is what I have so far, is this the correct approach? What am I missing? This is a custom field script using Groovy in ScriptRunner.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;

//managers
def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();

//gather the fields needed
def field1 = CustomFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Field 1")
def field2 = CustomFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Field 2")

//gather the values of the fields
def field1Value = issue.getCustomFieldValue(Field1).getValue()
def field2Value = issue.getCustomFieldValue(Field2).getValue()
if (field1Value == "Agree" && field2Value == "Agree"){
    def field3 = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Field 3")
    issue.setCustomFieldValue(field3, "Agree")
} else {
    issue.setCustomFieldValue(field3, "Disagree")
}
```

Comment: is it working?  what's not working? PS: Capitals to start classes, lower-case letters to start variables, so `field2`, not `Field2`. This is a convention that stops you falling into  potential pitfalls later on when Groovy may guess you're talking about a class

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the variable cases, I usually follow the convention but rushed to get the question in here.  When I test this script in Script Runner, I'm receiving the following error on all the 'issue' calls: The variable [issue] is undeclared.  This is a scripted field that will run as a post-function for whatever "issue" it is opened in in the Jira workflow. I'm confused on how to declare issue when I figured I was using it as an imported package above to execute the methods getCustomFieldValue and setCustomFieldValue.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask Atlassian. From my understanding, `issue` is provided for you, but it's not a Groovy thing, it's a Script Runner thing. Maybe you're somehow running the code in the wrong context. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/support

Comment: Figured out what the issue was...Emmanual was correct with the context as I was running this in Scriptrunner that was not implemented with Behaviours nor was it added in the context of a 'Scripted Field' which is required if you're going to call the Issue object within the context of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the issue was...Emmanual was correct with the context as I was running this in Scriptrunner that was not implemented with Behaviours nor was it added in the context of a 'Scripted Field' which is required if you're going to call the Issue object within the context of that issue.